# Different color chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have 2 kinds of charts,pie chart and column chart.

I present the same data of both charts, the problem is that color that presents each equipment is not the same in both of them.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The chart legend uses color fields to match the legend items to the
>   visible data points. The legend can only show one color field per
>   legend item (data series); hence, it shows the color of the first data
>   point within that series. Remember this when you use expressions to
>   dynamically determine the color of individual data points within a
>   series; the legend item always shows the actual color of the first
>   data point.

Using the same legend order in both charts should do the trick.

> Series are ordered in the legend according to the order that they are
>   processed by the Reporting Services processing engine. You can change
>   the order by changing the order of fields in the data fields
>   drop-zone. If you are using series grouping, the series data is not
>   known until processing, so that there is no way for you to re-order
>   these items.

If you're using series, which you probably are, you should make sure they're ordered correctly before sending them to the reporter.

Another solution is to create a custom legend for your charts. Which gives you a lot more control, especially if you define a custom color palette aswell.

> You can get more flexibility and control over the legend by generating
>   your own custom legend by using a table or a matrix. The easiest way
>   to synchronize the colors in the chart with your custom legend is to
>   define your own custom chart color palette.
>
> **To build a custom legend**
>
> 1. Add a table data region to the report.
>      Place the table next to the chart and bind it to the same dataset as the chart.
> 2. Mirror the chart grouping structure in the table by adding table
>      groups.
>      If the chart uses series groupings, add them to the table by
>      adding table groups that are based on the same group expression as
>      the one in the chart series groupings. Then add chart category
>      groupings (if present) as inner table groups.
>
>    In general, if the
>      chart has m series grouping and n category grouping, you add m+n
>      table groups for your custom legend.
>
>    For the individual table
>      groups, make sure to show only the group header (which will contain
>      the legend description). Also, remove the table detail row unless
>      you want to use the table detail rows to simulate a chart data
>      table.
> 3. Design the custom legend.
>      Add a rectangle for the color field of the
>      custom legend. For example, you might add it to the first table
>      column. As indicated in step 2, you should only have group header
>      rows in the table. The rectangle goes into the innermost group
>      header level.
>
>    Set the rectangle BackgroundColor property to the equivalent expression used on the chart data point's fill color. In the most
>      trivial case, the expression would just contain one grouping value as
>      in the following code.
>
>    ```
>    =Code.GetColor(Fields!Country.Value)
>    ```
>
>    For the legend text, use either the same expression as in the category and series group/label expressions, or experiment until you
>      achieve the legend description text that you want.

**Sources:**

- [Get More Out of SQL Server Reporting Services Charts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [Formatting the Legend on a Chart](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677428(v=sql.100).aspx)